# Question about signed release flutter app with firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-play-services, signed-apk

I know the question is rather trivial and stupid, but I really need a solid confirmation.
The only things that matter for firebase + flutter are: SHA-1, google-services.json file, application ID and dependencies?
Suppose I added a debug and signed SHAs to the firebase, added a json file to the project, and then compiled the signed release and published it on Google Play. So after this, if I continue to create signed versions of the same application for testing, will they still connect to the firebase in the same way and will not affect the main version? Therefore, no matter in what quantities or versions they should all work, if the contents of json are the same and they have the same identifier?